# OpenMPI : computation speed is different between different nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi

I am sort of new to the parallel computing and have encountered a problem using OpenMPI.  I have an application in main node from which I sent out strings to another node. The sending speed is much faster than the computation speed, should I create a queue in a thread in the second node to store the data ? Or is there other better solutions ?

Comment: There's not really enough information here to tell what you're trying to do. Are you saying that sending a string between nodes doesn't take as long as doing a bunch of computation? That's not overly surprising.

Comment: @WesleyBland passing message is faster but the computation in the second node takes much longer, even I have a queue to store the strings, I think the application in main node still needs to wait for the slower to finish, is it correct ? Is there any other strategy ?

Comment: You cannot outrun the slowest part of the program. You can only use non-blocking communication to overlay it with computation and thus save on some small amount of time. In any case, if your program is really computationally intensive, adding more nodes will help.

Comment: @HristoIliev Would you please elaborate on "non-blocking" communication on this case ?

Comment: `MPI_Isend` + `MPI_Wait` and/or `MPI_Irecv` + `MPI_Wait`. It is all part of the MPI standard and found in any MPI tutorial.

Comment: @HristoIliev But the blocking communication does not cause problem at all in my case.

Comment: Non-blocking communication is about overlapping outstanding communication with computation, i.e. doing them both at the same time, thus saving time.